# How can I Restrict S3 Bucket Uploads to Specific Client IP Addresses?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cloud, backend, aws-policies

I'm implementing a bucket policy to allow only specific IP addresses to upload objects and make requests to my S3 bucket. Here's the policy I've set up:

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "my_policy_id",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "my_sid",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucket/*",
            "Condition": {
                "NotIpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "203.0.113.45/32"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However, when I upload an object from a device using the public ip address placed in the policy, it gives me AccessDenied error.
And when checking the AWS s3 access log, I got this log entry that states the PUT request comes from the ip address *15.236.X.X* which is probably an AWS server. (e.g. load balancer).

Here is the Log (with sensitive information hidden):

> e92b220a3fe2f81face90796921ec9cdfb07349f2e79acb1f53a5aa5ce26 testbucket [08/Nov/2023:13:45:39 +0000] 15.236.X.X arn:aws:iam::[AWS Account ID]:user/[IAM User] REST.PUT.OBJECT foo.txt "PUT /foo.txt HTTP/1.1" 200 - - 0 30 10 "-" "[User-Agent Header] Resource" -[Request Authorization Header] SigV4 ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 AuthHeader testbucket.s3.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com TLSv1.2 - -

Is there a way to limit S3 bucket uploads to only allow specific client IP addresses?

I got information about the IP address in log from this page:
https://en.ntunhs.net/IPInfo/EN/15/236.htm

Edit1: I didn't set any load-balancer in the entire account.
Edit2: The IP in config is a dummy one, and a lambda function gets triggered when an object is uploaded.

Comment: You need to configure the load balancer to forward the client ip address

Comment: How is the client actually performing the upload? Is it making an AWS API call to perform an S3 PUT operation directly? Or is it uploading to some EC2 server or something, that then sends the file to S3? If the client is connecting directly to the AWS API to perform an S3 PUT, then there is definitely not any load balancer involved.

Comment: Assuming the IP you showed in your config file isn't a dummy address, it's a RFC 5737 internal IP.  In other words, the IP address that S3 sees is the NAT server, not their internal IP.  The other IP, 15.236.0.0/15, is a range reserved for EC2, which is I'm guessing the public IP that you should be whitelisting.

Comment: @MarkB The client is making AWS API calls directly, and there is a lambda function that gets triggered when an upload event happens.

Comment: @AnonCoward The IP address in config is dummy

Comment: I think you have to have something in front of S3 for the IP address to be changing like that. Are you going through CloudFront, or AWS Global Accelerator or something? I have S3 buckets with IP address rules in the policy like that, and they work fine, the incoming IPs don't get changed into internal AWS IPs.